# Recover pictures from damaged phone

Tags: ios, iphone, photos, recovery

My iPhone 4 was submerged in water weeks ago.  It will turn on, but the slide to turn on/enter password is not working so I can not access anything on the phone. I want to recover pictures and videos before I throw the phone away. I thought they were backed up to my iCloud, but they are not. When I plug the phone into my computer to download them, says there are no pictures or videos on my phone. Any suggestions on how to recover these?